# Laravel can't use session when set with ajax

Tags: php, laravel, session

My Controller.php

```
$request->session()->put('used_coupons', json_encode($dizi[$cart[0]->cart_id]));
$request->session()->save();
$response = ['result' => true];
echo json_encode($response);
```

My Ajax

```js
$('button.481andrb2n1mayore').click(function() {
    const code = $('input#1bwbabchfb4n2eroy').val()
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'n3bqshfia5m1': code, 'amdj5h3b1avzfhfn42ll__': $('input#ey4b1bVDBT4m3n1b48qnabe_______').val()},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('input#1bwbabchfb4n2eroy').val('Please wait!');
            $('input#1bwbabchfb4n2eroy').attr('disabled', true);
            $('button.481andrb2n1mayore').attr('disabled', true)
            $('div.couponCodeMessageDiv').css('display', 'none');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data.result == false) {
                $('div.couponCodeMessageDiv').css('display', 'block');
                $('div.couponCodeMessageDiv span').html(data.message);
            }
            if (data.result == true) {
                location.reload();
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('div.couponCodeMessageDiv').css('display', 'block');
            $('div.couponCodeMessageDiv span').html("Error!");
            alert('hata')
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            $('input#1bwbabchfb4n2eroy').val('deneme20');
            $('input#1bwbabchfb4n2eroy').attr('disabled', false);
            $('button.481andrb2n1mayore').attr('disabled', false)
        }
    });
})
```

I can see the session but after I refresh the page session is gone.
If I update the database which is nothing about session data, while this process, the session saving successfully, however I don't want to keep data in database or update.
How to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: What is `$request->session()->save()`? I don't think you need that.

Comment: I tried with or without $request->session()->save() but still not working

Comment: What do you mean by `after I refresh the page session is gone`? Are you firing another AJAX request? What code are you running to determine the "session is gone"?

Comment: Let's think like we are customer and we want to use coupon code we enter this code to the input and click to apply button. The ajax gets code and send with post request. Then the coupon saved to the session with controller. And then controller send ajax to success json. Then page need to be refreshed to blade can show customer that coupon is applied. I can set the session but when I refresh page the session is seems empty ("") I am checking with other route which runs dd(session()->all());

Comment: If you do not refresh the page, I don't think the session message will show. From what I remember, you cannot treat session as a reactive property. If you want to pass a message after an ajax request, you need to append it into the response itself

Comment: We need more info to help debug. For example, are you using Web or API route files? Laravel won't save session data for API routes. Can you get any session data to persist at all?

Comment: Well I am using Web Route files, and edited kernel.php file SessionStart class to middleware group. I can use session in other functions like register or login but when I use ajax I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, problem solved with changing the session name from 'used_coupons' to 'usedCoupons'. I don't know why it is solved with renaming, it's laravel not a surprise.